# Help on a simple Monte-Carlo Significance test (probability of occurrence)

Tags: r, statistical-significance, monte-carlo

I would like to perform a statistical significance based on Monte Carlo simulation in R but I don't know how to formulate this correctly.

I have the following data set:

[Link to data]
(https://www.dropbox.com/s/29zgm8nm39qyh7m/data_rainfall.csv?dl=0)

There are four columns (Year, Month, Day, Phase, and Rainfall).

[Problem]

I want to know the likelihood of occurrence (significance) of getting

(a) rainfall below 5 mm/day for at least 3 consecutive days AND whose first day is in phase 1 (in each year).

[Here's what I have so far]

```
dat<-read.csv("data_rainfall.csv",header=T)
dat2<-as.data.frame(cbind(dat$phase,dat$Rainfall))
```

The significance function:

```
sig.test <- function (){
s1 <- dat2[sample(1:nrow(dat2),5,replace=T),]
  res<-sum(rle((s1$V1<5))$lengths >=3 & rle((s1$V2==1))$lengths >=3 )
return(sum(res)>0)
}

runs <- 1000
sig <- sum(replicate(runs,sig.test()))/runs
```

The result is always 1 which is odd.  I think there is a problem with how I calculate. the p value.

How can I do this correctly in R?

I'll appreciate any help on this.

--Lyndz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a function to get at least 3 consecutive days less than 5 and first day is phase 1, using rle is ok, you need to get back the index:

```
dat2<-dat[,c("phase","Rainfall")]
RLE = rle(dat2$Rainfall<5)

Run Length Encoding
  lengths: int [1:728] 11 2 2 5 1 2 3 7 13 1 ...
  values : logi [1:728] TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE ...

start_idx = cumsum(c(1,RLE$lengths[-length(RLE$lengths)]))
head(start_idx)
[1]  1 12 14 16 21 22
```

And we use this to get back whether the first entry is a phase 3:

```
phase_at_start = dat2$phase[start_idx]
```

Then it's a matter of combining the booleans, and wrapping it into a function:

```
countruns = function(x){
RLE = rle(x$Rainfall<5)
start_idx = cumsum(c(1,RLE$lengths[-length(RLE$lengths)]))
phase_at_start = x$phase[start_idx]
sum(RLE$lengths>=3 & phase_at_start==3)
}
```

My suggestion is to permute the rainfall column, so that you preserve the structure and occurrence of phase in the first column. I suppose what you are interested in is whether it's by chance you see 3 consecutive days of low rainfall If this works you can go on and experiment with the other columns:

```
sim.test <- function (x){
x$Rainfall <- sample(x$Rainfall)
countruns(x)
}

runs <- 1000
sim <- replicate(runs,sig.test(dat))
hist(sim,br=100)
```

[image]

Comment: @StupidWold..Thank you for this. Just one question, how do I get the pvalue from the "sim"?

Comment: hmmmm what would you define as a p-value, probability of getting more runs or less runs? it would be (sum(sim>=countruns(dat2))+1)/(runs+1) or (sum(sim<=countruns(dat2))+1)/(runs+1)

Comment: from your data, I counted 22, whereas from the simulation you see you would expect around 33.. i guess it's less?

Comment: again, you know your data better than I do, you need to think about what you are simulating.. distribution of rainfall or something else

Comment: hmm..Thank you for this.. I just want to know whether the breaks (the three days with low rainfall occurred by chance). I am not sure how to get the pvalue from the histogram..If how many times the "22" is exceeded by the simulation? I am not sure...

Comment: like this no? https://www.biomedware.com/files/documentation/clusterseer/MCR/Calculating_Monte_Carlo_p-values.htm, i plotted the histogram to see that the simulation doesn't give me something weird

Comment: I tried to edit the sig function like this: `sig.test <- function (x){
x$Rainfall <- sample(x$Rainfall)
sum(countruns(x)>22)
}`. but what I am getting is just 1. `sim <- sum(replicate(runs,sig.test(dat)))/runs`

Comment: Yes!. The observed count is actually 22. So the the number of times this is exceeded by the 1000 simulation. But what I am getting is just 1 for the pvalue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107181/discussion-between-stupidwolf-and-lyndz).

Comment: I am back to this problem again. This time, I would like to test the significance for a particular Phase. For example, I'll test the significance for the occurrence of  3 consecutive days with less than 5 mm/day rainfall and with Phase 1. How can I do this based on the above script? I'll appreciate your help on this.